# What does record oriented data integration mean

Tags: jca

In this JCA tutorial [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2001/jw-1121-jca.html?page=3)

```
Data integration
Lastly, data-level integration implies that the data passed between systems will be in a data/record-oriented manner.
```

What is 'record-oriented'?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record-oriented_filesystem) is a pretty good description on a Record-oriented filesystem:

> In computer science, a record-oriented filesystem is a file system
>   where files are stored as collections of records. There are several
>   different record formats; the details vary depending on the particular
>   system. In general the formats can be fixed-length or variable length,
>   with different physical organizations or padding mechanisms; metadata
>   may be associated with the file records to define the record length,
>   or the data may be part of the record. Different methods to access
>   records may be provided, for example sequential, by key or by record
>   number.